# Python: How can I use ggplot with a simple 2 column array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, python-ggplot

I try to use [ggplot for python](https://pypi.org/project/ggplot/) I have the following data:

```
power_data = [[  4.13877565e+04,   2.34652000e-01],
[  4.13877565e+04,   2.36125000e-01],
[  4.13877565e+04,   2.34772000e-01],
...
[  4.13882896e+04,   2.29006000e-01],
[  4.13882896e+04,   2.29019000e-01],
[  4.13882896e+04,   2.28404000e-01]]
```

And I want to represent it in [ggplot](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/) with this:

```
print ggplot(aes(x='TIME', y='Watts'), data=power_data) + \
    geom_point(color='lightblue') + \
    geom_line(alpha=0.25) + \
    stat_smooth(span=.05, color='black') + \
    ggtitle("Power comnsuption over 13 hours") + \
    xlab("Time") + \
    ylab("Watts")
```

but get the error:

```
  File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\ggplot\ggplot.py", line 59, in __init__
    for ae, name in self.aesthetics.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
>>>
```

I don't know what the line `aes(x='TIME', y='Watts')` should be doing.

How can I format the `power_data` list so I can use it with ggplot, I want first column reprezentedon a time `x` axis and second column on a power `y` axis?

If I am trying with the `meat` example it doesn't show nothing it only shows

```
>>> print (ggplot(aes(x='date', y='beef'), data=meat) + \
...     geom_line())
<ggplot: (20096197)>
>>>
```

What should I do to further show the graphic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were 3 important steps that I missed:

**1)** First the data needs to be in a format like this:

```
[{'TIME': 41387.756495162001, 'Watts': 0.234652},
 {'TIME': 41387.756500821, 'Watts': 0.236125},
 {'TIME': 41387.756506480997, 'Watts': 0.23477200000000001},
 {'TIME': 41387.756512141001, 'Watts': 0.23453099999999999},
...
 {'TIME': 41387.756574386003, 'Watts': 0.23558699999999999},
 {'TIME': 41387.756580046, 'Watts': 0.23508899999999999},
 {'TIME': 41387.756585706004, 'Watts': 0.235041},
 {'TIME': 41387.756591365003, 'Watts': 0.23541200000000001},
 {'TIME': 41387.756597013002, 'Watts': 0.23461699999999999},
 {'TIME': 41387.756602672998, 'Watts': 0.23483899999999999}]
```

**2)** Then the data needs to be decorated with `DataFrame` with

```
powd = DataFrame(data2)
```

**3)** Without the `plt.show(1)` the plot will not show

Here is the code to solve the above:

```py
from pandas import DataFrame
data2 = []
for i in range(0,len(power_data)):
    data2.append({'TIME': power_data[i][0], 'Watts': power_data[i][1]})

powd = DataFrame(data2)
print powd

# the above can be changed with this line:
# powd = DataFrame(power_data, columns=['TIME', 'Watts'])
# see sugestion in comments 

print ggplot(aes(x='TIME', y='Watts'), data=powd) + \
    geom_point(color='lightblue') + \
    geom_line(alpha=0.25) + \
    stat_smooth(span=.05, color='black') + \
    ggtitle("Power comnsuption over 13 hours") + \
    xlab("Time") + \
    ylab("Watts")
```

**Or alternatively** in one pass without the `for` as provided in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19497282/python-how-can-i-use-ggplot-with-a-simple-2-column-array/19499418#comment29203743_19499418):

```
powd = DataFrame(power_data, columns=['TIME', 'Watts'])
print ggplot(aes(x='TIME', y='Watts'), data=powd) + \
        geom_point(color='lightblue') + \
        geom_line(alpha=0.25) + \
        stat_smooth(span=.05, color='black') + \
        ggtitle("Power comnsuption over 13 hours") + \
        xlab("Time") + \
        ylab("Watts")
```

Comment: FYI, you didn't need to change the format of the data. You can create the dataframe that you need using the original format with `powd = DataFrame(power_data, columns=['TIME', 'Watts'])`

Answer (score 0):

We can also use another function from ggplot library **qplot** to plot the graph. Assuming the above dataset **power_data** as input. We can plot it as:

`import qplot from ggplot 
 qplot(power_data[:,0], power_data[:,1], type='l')`